# Getting the first child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have div with two a tags in it I want to write css for the fist a tag.

Here is the HTML:.

```
<div id="Text">
    <br />                
    <a href="http://farsnews.com/newstext.php?nn=13920430001427#sthash.BOTOvYwM.dpuf">فارس نیوز</a>
    <a href="http://farsnews.com/newstext.php?nn=13920430001427#sthash.BOTOvYwM.dpuf">فارس نیوز</a>
</div>
```

and here is my css code:

```css
#Text a:last-child{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red; /*rgb(18, 139, 235)*/
}
```

Comment: So you want to style it according to :first-child?

Comment: Saying "Please dont give me negative mark just help me" is only going to get you even more downvotes. Just don't say it at all, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `a` is not the first-child within its parent that is `DIV#text`  . The CSS first-child pseudo-class operates as follows:

```
The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.
```

When ready very literally, it will only apply to an element that is the first child within its parent. It does not take into consideration the context you (mentally) create when you add the additional class selectors to it.

When applying the pseudo-class the browser doesn't understand the context created by the selector. Basically, its checking that the element matches the selector `#text a`, then asking the question, "Is this the first child within the parent?". It asks this question without any consideration of the aforementioned selector. In your case, the answer is no since there is another element before the first `a`. that is `<br/>`(Same thing applied for `last-child` also)

In your example, the element `<br/>` is actually the first child.

**so the conclusion is-**

If you want to give style for `a:first-child` then it must be a first child of its parent i.e `DIV#text`

right now your first child is **BR** so please remove it

**OR Else assign**

```
#Text a.q {
  ...
}
```

**Or else**

```
#Text a:first-of-type {...}

The :first-of-type selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
#Text a:first-of-type{
    /* css */
}
```

This will select the first `<a>` tag inside of #Text

Answer (score 3):

```
#Text a.q {
  //css
}
```

you can do it like this

Comment: Sorry how about the edited form both a tags dont have any calss

Comment: then use `#Text a:first-of-type` like @TotalWipeOut wrote :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write as follow :

```
div a.q {
  text-decoration: none;
   color: red; /*rgb(18, 139, 235)*/
}
```

or

```
  #Text a.q {
      text-decoration: none;
       color: red; /*rgb(18, 139, 235)*/
    }
```

Comment: for that you can use #Text a:first-of-type

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#Text a:first-child{
    /*your css */
}
```